# Updating Jupyter notebook kernel after changing the virtual environment it's based off of

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-venv

I have a Python package that I am editing and the edits didn't seem to be working after re-importing everything in my Jupyter notebook. I reinstalled the package in the virtual environment and made a new iPython kernel and it's working now.

Is there some way to update the kernel along with the virtual environment as changes are made to the source files of the package?

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating a jupyter cell repeatedly. For example, in one cell:

```
import foo
```

and in another cell:

```
result = foo.bar(7)
```

Put both of those in a single cell,
so you will re-import current foo code before executing it.